# Jython: subprocess.Popen runs out of file descriptors

Tags: python, file-io, resources, jython, popen

I'm using the Jython 2.51 implementation of Python to write a script that repeatedly invokes another process via `subprocess.Popen` and uses `PIPE` to pipe `stdout` and `stderr` to the parent process and `stdin` to the child process.  After several hundred loop iterations, I seem to run out of file descriptors.

The [Python subprocess documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) mentions very little about freeing file descriptors, other than the `close_fds` option, which isn't described very clearly (Why should there be any file descriptors besides 0, 1 and 2 open in the first place?).  I'm assuming that in CPython, reference counting takes care of the resource freeing issue.  What's the proper way to make sure all descriptors get freed when one is done with a `Popen` object in Jython?

Edit:  Just in case it makes a difference, this is a multithreaded program, so there are several `Popen` processes running simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

This only answers part of your question, but my understanding is that, when you spawn a new process, it normally inherits all the handles of the parent process.  That includes such things as open files and sockets that you're listening on.

On UNIX, that's a side-effect of using 'fork', which duplicates the current process and all of its handles before loading the new executable.  On Windows it's more explicit, but Python does it anyway, to try to match the behavior across platforms as much as possible.

The close_fds option, when True, closes all these inherited handles after spawning the subprocess, so the new executable starts with a clean slate.  But if your subprocesses are run one at a time, and terminating when they're done, then this shouldn't be the problem.