# How to distribute libraries used within my Jython war?

Tags: web-applications, import, jython, web-inf

I've read the answers to the related questions about managing used libraries in a Jython application:

[How can I install various Python libraries in Jython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787015/how-i-install-various-python-libraries-in-jython)

[Best method for managing Jython packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493307/best-method-for-managing-jython-packages)

But I don't want to put those libraries in a location on my system. I would like to distribute them with my Jython webapp. It seems I once managed to install a library to my webapp's WEB-INF/lib/Lib/site-packages/ directory, but I can't figure out how to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

For regular Jython apps I've had success using [OneJar](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/DeploymentTargets.html#deploying-a-single-jar) to package all my dependencies. I haven't tried it, but it looks like you should be able to package that unified jar into a war package. It's convoluted, but it strikes me that solutions to these practical Jython questions often are. As an alternative it might suffice to stick the jython jar into the /web/lib folder in your jar and then bootstrap your jython code with a java snippet. Good luck, I'm interested to hear how you resolve this.

Comment: It does sound complicated, I'll have to study up whether this does what I need. And I didn't understand the alternative part. I shelved the project meanwhile, so it might be a while before I get back to it again. Thanks for now.